# How do I get two divs next to eachother, but spaced?

Tags: html, css

I am making a game for a school assignment (mastermind), but i'm having trouble getting the divs to do what I want. I have a board div, with multiple other divs inside it ( 5 each row). I am now planning on making a second div next to it to have it display scores. However I can't seem to get the "scoresheet" div next to the "board" div. I have just picked up programming so my code may be really primitive or ineffecient. this is what I have thus far:

```
<div id="board">
        <div id="turn0">
        <div id="space0.0" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0.1" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0.2" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0.3" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="table0">
        <table>

            <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
```

this is one row of the board, this code is copied with each row of the board.
the table is for displaying white or black pins based on the amount of colors you guessed correctly, the first four divs are previous displays for showing the colors you chose for the previous turn. the "board" div is used for displaying previous turns.
this is my CSS code on the "board" div:

```
#board{
    width: 335px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

this is the CSS for the first four squares inside the "board" div:

```
  .spacex {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 6px;
        vertical-align: center;
}
```

and lastly the CSS for the small table:

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 22px;
    width: 50px;
    margin; 4px;
}
```

I was thinking of having the "scoresheet" div stick to the right side of the page, up against the scrollbar.
I also don't know if using a table to display the amount of white and black pins is the best course of action, if you know a more efficiënt or smarter piece of coding then please let me know.
I am not at all familiar with more intricate pieces of coding, so if you could explain the steps, and function of each piece of code that would be much, much appreciated.
Thanks in advance for all the help.

---

I have now managed to get another div that will display highscores and other usefull information, which was the struglle I was having: to get a div that displays information to be placed to the right of the "board" div. It turned out be simpler than i thought, I just had to give the div a top and right value and posistion. While you all have been a great help, I still have two more issues remaining concerning the placement of my divs. Right now i have a button that is going to check if the guessed colors match the coputer generated color code, however I cant get the position of the button to change. I also have a problem with the the divs inside the "board" div not showing correctly. The whole concept behind the code is hard to explain, so I will copy the code I have thus far below:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Master Mind </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    <h1> Master Mind </h1>
    </p>

    <div id="turn-interactive">
        <div id="choosecolor0" class="colorfield"></div>
        <div id="choosecolor1" class="colorfield"></div>
        <div id="choosecolor2" class="colorfield"></div>
        <div id="choosecolor3" class="colorfield"></div>
        <form> <input type="button" value="Check!"name="button" class="button"></form>
    </div>
    <div id="board">
        <div id="turn0">
        <div id="space0-0" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0-1" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0-2" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0-3" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="table0">

        <table>

            <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div id="board">
        <div id="beurt0">
        <div id="space0_0" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0_1" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0_2" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="space0_3" class="spacex"></div>
        <div id="table0">

        <table>

            <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>  
    <aside><div id="infobar" class="infobar"></div></aside>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 99%;
    width: 99%;
}

div {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.infobar{
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    right: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: white;
}
.button{
 display: block;
 height: 100px;
 width: 300px;
 background: #34696f;
 border: 2px solid rgba(33, 68, 72, 0.59);
 position: static;
 top: 50%;
 left: 75%;
}
}

.spacex {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 6px;
}

.colorfield {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height:120px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    left: 50%;
}

#board{
    width: 350px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#turn-interactive{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    top: 15%;

}

table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 22px;
    width: 50px;
    margin; 4px;

}
```

the idea is to later (when I start coding the javascript) to have the values of the four colorfields displayed copied down below inside the "Board" div. The table inside the board div is for displaying the amount of white and black pins ( four colorfields, four squares inside the table). If you run the current code you can see that the four divs that are supposed to be displayed inside the "board" div before the table are not showing correctly, and are just creating a big black border inside the board." I have no clue of how I'm supposed to fix this. The four divs did show up correctly when i had just one row of "four colordivs-one table" ofcourse there is going to be a history of turns so I need muliple rows of four colordivs followed by a table displaying pins. Since it did work with only one row that had a table I'm guessing that the table is the troubleshooter. I translated the div ID's and class names from Dutch to English so it's clear what's what.
Again, thanks a bunch for the help.

PS. Since the website also is going to need a javascript code later on I thought that i should add the tag. Sorry about that, since my question indeed wasn't javascript related.

Comment: the point in your id names are going to be a problem, the style will read : #space0.1 like id space0 that has class 1 ... use an undescore or else but a point ;)   ?? it works, isn't http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyRVbx

Comment: Tables usually have CSS issues, when trying to style the tables with a CSS selectors. They may not work properly, which is why people prefer to use div & span tags with CSS selectors instead of tables. However, tables can be used for tabular data. Div tags are block level elements. They stack like vertical blocks, unless you use CSS properties like float:left; or display:inline-block. Span tags are inline elements. The are like words in a sentence, which are placed horizontally one-after-another.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 as this is a good place to ask for programming help, even if it's for a homework assignment. We're all learning & helping each other to become better programmers by sharing knowledge & expertise. Too bad SO didn't exist when I was in school. I hope that you get an A+ on this assignment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a table to host your score is a god idea.

You could use `position: absolute` to position you table according to another element. This element is its *Containing Block* and you can indicate it is your board game by adding a `position: relative` to it.
If you do so, you can add `left: 100%` to your score sheet to make it stick on the right of your board.

```css
#board {
  position: relative;
  width: 335px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
#scoresheet {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 52px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#scoresheet td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <table id="scoresheet">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this idea a lot, but I'd suggest using right:0; instead of left:100%; The reason being is that you can then add margin-right: 15px; & it will push off to the right side of the browser. Otherwise, the 100% would have to be messed with & fine-tuned & re-messed with to create a value like left:99.98765%.

Comment: @Clomp If you use `right: 0` or `right: 15px` the score sheet will be **on** the game board. The two solution have a different design, it depends on what was asked.

Comment: Yes, that's why I just posted an answer which straightens out the HTML tag issue. Then the right: 15px; can be used. Usually scoresheets wouldn't be part of the actual gameboard layer. Otherwise, a game piece could overlap a player's score. The scoresheet could appear on top of the gameboard with a transparent background, if it's given a z-index layer.

Answer (score 1):

I made a CodePen of your example:  http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/MyJGaz?editors=1100

As @GCyrillus pointed out, you're going to want to swap the points/periods in your IDs with hyphens/dashes or underscores. I've used dashes here, but do what you want.

It's not clear from your question if you want the score table to appear inside the board (which is how it's coded) or at the upper right corner, regardless of the board. I added the following CSS to your example:

```
#table0 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

If you want the table to be inside the board, you just need to add `position:relative` to the `#board`. I've added that already, but commented it out. I also commented out the `left:50%` which isn't doing anything at all in the current code and just mucks things up if/when you change the position of `#board`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can't put the scoresheet table next to the gameboard div, is because the table tag is nested inside of the gameboard div. So the gameboard div wraps around the table. Here is how to solve this issue: "However I can't seem to get the "scoresheet" div next to the "board" div."

Change this:

```
<div id="board">
   ...
   <table>
   ...
   </table>
</div>
```

To this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/p12ryvbn/)

```
<div id="board">
    ...
</div>
<table id="scoresheet">
    ...
</table>
```

To make them appear side-by-side, apply a left float to both of them:

```
#board, 
#scoresheet {
   float: left;
}
```

You can use that same float:left trick to horizontally align the spacex div tags into a row of squares. This would solve this issue: "I have a board div, with multiple other divs inside it ( 5 each row)." To create multiple rows, wrap them in a row div, which doesn't have a float applied to it.

```
<div id="row1" class="rows">
    <div id="space0.0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space0.1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space0.2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space0.3" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space0.4" class="spacex"></div>
</div>
<div id="row2" class="rows">
    <div id="space1.0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space1.1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space1.2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space1.3" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space1.4" class="spacex"></div>
</div>

.spacex {
   float: left;
}
```

Try giving .spacex a border, background-color & margins/padding to style them up! Good luck! :)